# Оптимизировать цикл парсинга

Tags: php, парсер

Есть некоторый цикл (представлен частично от основного кода, но суть передает):

```
foreach ($links as $key => $value) 
  { 

//  H1
    $sostav_result = $document->find('h1')[0]->text();

    $sostav_result = preg_replace('/\bвалун\b/u', "камень", $sostav_result);
    $sostav_result = preg_replace('/\bщебень\b/u', "камень", $sostav_result);
    $sostav_result = preg_replace('/\bщебенка\b/u', "камень", $sostav_result);
    $sostav_result = preg_replace('/\bкаменюка\b/u', "камень", $sostav_result);

}
```

Цикл обходит ряд страниц, получая на каждой значение из H1, и **находя синонимы заменяет их на нужное слово**. Собственно эта процедура и занимает тем **больше времени, чем больше указано синонимов** для замены (а может их быть 100+).

Вопрос: как возможно оптимизировать данный процесс? Каким другим способом замены возможно воспользоваться или оптимизировать текущий?

Comment: попробуйте одной регуляркой. тут есть плюсы что не надо будет проходить исходную строку несколько раз, но минус в в альтернативах в самой регулярке. Так что надо делать замеры на реальных данных, что выгоднее `/\b(валун|щебен(ь|ка)|каменюка)\b/u`

Comment: Вариант 2, если строка H1 довольно короткая, то взять отдельные слова (любые) и проверить их наличие в хеше (`array('щебенка'=>1, 'щебень'=>1, 'валун'=>1)`)

Comment: @Mike спасибо за варианты! Но первый, кажется, еще дольше занимает времени. Хотя, не уверен. Почему то, времязатраты на работу скрипта сильно разнятся даже при одинаковой конфигурации. От 17с до 35с